# Shared legend of charts in react-highcharts?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

How can one have two charts with a shared legend (which controls both charts) using react-highcharts?

A solutions using jQuery is provided in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teEQ3/) but I am unable to sort out how to do it (& have components' options reference other components) in React.

Jquery:

```
$(function () {
$('#container1').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        id: 'someId',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
$('#container2').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function (event) {
                    var XYZ = $('#container1').highcharts(),
                        series = XYZ.get(this.options.id); //get corresponding series

                    if (series) {
                        if (this.visible) {
                            series.hide();
                        } else {
                            series.show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        id: 'someId',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

});

(works)

Pointers appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the wanted result similarly in React. Below you can find a working example with `highcharts-react-official` wrapper:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        events: {
            legendItemClick: (function(component) {
                return function() {
                    const chart = component.chart1.current.chart;
                    const series = chart.get(this.options.id);

                    if (series) {
                        if (this.visible) {
                            series.hide();
                        } else {
                            series.show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            })(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/oo0q4832jy

Docs: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/blob/master/README.md